# check one of the fields is not null sql server

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with 7 columns which one of them is null or not null

```
SELECT *
FROM   V_TOUTES_SIM_ACTIVE vt
WHERE  VT.ID_PLAT_BUS_NUM IS NOT NULL
        OR VT.ID_PLAT_BUS_SERIE IS NOT NULL
        OR VT.ID_PLAT_FLEETLT_NUM IS NOT NULL
        OR VT.ID_PLAT_FLEETLT_SERIE IS NOT NULL
        OR VT.ID_PLAT_FLEET_NUM IS NOT NULL
        OR VT.ID_PLAT_FLEET_SERIE IS NOT NULL
        OR VT.ID_PLAT_TRACK IS NOT NULL
```

How can  I specify that one or more of this id is not null, any suggestions?

Comment: What does specify mean?

Comment: What's wrong with your current query?

Comment: Do you mean a check constraint?

Comment: this can be much efficient to add `CONSTRAINT`  on table

Comment: Please add some sample data and your expected result.

Answer (score 0):

You have a very vague question, so here is a stab in the dark.
This query adds extra columns showing which fields are null or not.

```
SELECT *
,ID_PLAT_BUS_NUM_IS_NULL        =  case when VT.ID_PLAT_BUS_NUM is null then 1 else 0 end
,ID_PLAT_BUS_SERIE_IS_NULL      =  case when VT.ID_PLAT_BUS_SERIE is null then 1 else 0 end
,ID_PLAT_FLEETLT_NUM_IS_NULL    =  case when VT.ID_PLAT_FLEETLT_NUM is null then 1 else 0 end
,ID_PLAT_FLEETLT_SERIE_IS_NULL  =  case when VT.ID_PLAT_FLEETLT_SERIE is null then 1 else 0 end
,ID_PLAT_FLEET_NUM_IS_NULL      =  case when VT.ID_PLAT_FLEET_NUM is null then 1 else 0 end
,ID_PLAT_FLEET_SERIE_IS_NULL    =  case when VT.ID_PLAT_FLEET_SERIE is null then 1 else 0 end
,ID_PLAT_TRACK_IS_NULL          =  case when VT.ID_PLAT_TRACK is null then 1 else 0 end
FROM   V_TOUTES_SIM_ACTIVE vt
WHERE  VT.ID_PLAT_BUS_NUM IS NOT NULL
        OR VT.ID_PLAT_BUS_SERIE IS NOT NULL
        OR VT.ID_PLAT_FLEETLT_NUM IS NOT NULL
        OR VT.ID_PLAT_FLEETLT_SERIE IS NOT NULL
        OR VT.ID_PLAT_FLEET_NUM IS NOT NULL
        OR VT.ID_PLAT_FLEET_SERIE IS NOT NULL
        OR VT.ID_PLAT_TRACK IS NOT NULL
```